# ошибка: Class 'app\models\UploadForm' not found

Tags: php, yii2

Я новичок.
через gii создал контроллер, модель, crud.
Задача: реализовать загрузку файлов.
Проблема: страница index выдает ошибку "Class 'app\models\UploadForm' not found".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в модели вроде бы указал

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
public $imageFile;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
    ];
}



public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $this->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

контроллер:

```
use Yii;
use app\models\Murals;
use app\models\SearchMurals;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\UploadForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
class MuralController extends Controller
{


public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new UploadForm();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->
imageFileUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'imageFile');
        if ($model->upload()) {

            return;
        }
    }

    return $this->render('index', ['model' => $model]);
}`
```

не понимаю что куда и как. Помогите.

Comment: ну php не может найти класс, вы уверены что UploadForm() находиться в нужном месте? имею ввиду в нужной папке.

Comment: В папке Models есть файл UploadForm.php?

Comment: да, в этом была проблема. Точнее, еще и в этом. Спасибо.